# Android Emulator Warnings (QStandardPaths, GLES1, FramebufferData)

Tags: android-studio, emulation

When I start my App in the Android Studio Emulator (just plays a sound downloaded from the internet) I get following response in the Event log:

20:10   Emulator: Warning: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.android-studio', please create it with 0700 permissions. ((null):0, (null))

20:10   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

20:10   Emulator: Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.

20:11   Gradle build finished in 8 s 591 ms

20:11   Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a texture is deleted without unbinding FBO

The last warning shows up multiple times. Please help me. Greetings, Philipp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did what the log says. So I created a folder with the name `snap.android-studio` in `/run/user/1000/` with the permission `0700` (it was the default setting). The warning vanished.

I hope it is a useful answer for you.